# Deploying Asp.net Core 3.1 does not work on Windows server

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, windows-server-2012, blazor-server-side, iis-10

I have this Asp.net Core 3.1 developed on VS2019 preview.
basically it is a blazor server-side app with referenced assemblies and some nugets.

it runs fine on VS2019 and on my IIS after publishing to folder..
problem is when i move that folder to windows server machine with IIS installed and everything.
an error with 500 code appears.

one thing i noticed here..the log_error.txt file in the server it points out an exception
,and that exception *-what ever it is-* showing the error line of the startup.cs file with my laptop directory path !

i mean it shows this `C:/mrmeeez/..../Startup.cs line 411`

but this path does not exists in the windows server machine
it supposed to be `F:/.... somthing/Startup.cs line 411`

i don't know if it has something too do with the problem anyway..or maybe my assemblies and nugets not shipping correctly to the server

windows server machine is working fine , i tried blazor app template and it ran perfectly.
i need your help guys , Thanks !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok , i found it

i don't know for sure is this related to asp.net core 3.1
because i deployed asp.net core 2.1 months ago and it was fine

anyway i used the development exception page in the final publish to see what causing the error and showed this

> UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' is denied.

and after searching for that i found the answer from a guy in github
it seems that the user IIS_IUSRS for this application pool -by default- does not have permissions to access that path

to solve this problem,either one of the two below:

1-Give IIS_IUSRS permissions to access the system files **-NOT RECOMANDED-**

2-Change the user of the your application pool to LocalSystem account in IIS by going to **Application Pools -> Right-Click your app -> Advance Settings -> Process Model section then change Identity**

Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/1983

Thanks!

Comment: Option 1 can be not recommended, but you can grant the actual application pool identity enough permissions on that `DataProtection-Keys` to resolve it. Option 2 is crazy, as no one should use LocalSystem, unless he/she knows what is going on. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities#application-pool-identity-accounts

Comment: Option 2 is not crazy if you know the app else it could be malware option 1 you are basically granting every app pool unnecessary permissions which is security threat

Comment: "if you know the app" is interesting, as web apps are often the first door to break in. I wonder how well you can "know" an app, considering its security relies on so many pieces, OS/web framework/the app itself, and holes are everywhere. Anyway, you can be quite confident that bad things never happens to you. I also commented on your assertion of option 1, because IIS_IUSRS shouldn't be used in the first place. What prevents you from using the actual application pool identity? Most organizations have strict rules and use dedicated service accounts.

Comment: it is my app , and i'm sure i won't harm my clients server
i made it clear in the question that it is my app
i developed it , i deployed it
so ""if you know the app" is interesting" is not actually interesting if you read the question carefully
you yourself said "Option 2 is crazy, as no one should use LocalSystem, unless he/she knows what is going on" yes , i know what is going on